# Indexing by word in a list

Tags: python

I feel like this is a really simple question,
but I need help figuring out.

So, I have the following:

```
str = 'hello world'
str.split()  # ['hello','world']
```

I want to index 'world' but str[1] returns 'e', which is the second character in the list.
How do I index by word instead of character?

Please help me out and thank you in advance.

(Please don't tell me to do str[5:]... I wanna know how to index words in general)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to index the *result* of `my_str.split()`:

```
my_str = "hello world"
words = my_str.split()
print words[1]
```

(Renamed the variable to `my_str` to avoid shadowing the built-in.)

Note that `my_str.split()` does not change `my_str` in any way.  String objects are immutable in Python and can't be changed.  Instead, `my_str.split()` returns a list of strings that can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is your string, not the result of `str.split()`. You need to assign the result to something (preferably something *not* called `str`, since that's the name of the builtin `str` type and also a rather bad name to use for a list, even one returned from `str.split()`.

```
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> l = s.split()
>>> l[1]
'world'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing `str`, which is a string (you didn't reassign value to `str` after splitting so it went down the drain).

Use

```
str.split()[1]
```

or even better save the split result, and index that:

```
spl = str.split()
spl[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list, instead of splitting in place:

```
str = 'hello world'
str_words = str.split()  # split returns a list

print str_words[0] # prints first word "hello"
```